# App script once a week asking for authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I did a script (I'm not a programer) and I'm running to get a csv from metabase question. The only problem is because once a week as asking me to authorize again.
It shows:

"Authorisation required" "A script attached to this document needs your permission to run."

[image: image step 01]

[image step 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV2q5.png)

[image step 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLPAB.png)

[image step 04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95dwq.png)

What can I do to authorize forever?

I need to have the authorization forever. Not needed to authorize once a week because I'm running on time-base and automated. The code is below.
I have two files Code.gs and Code2.gs - on the first one I have another code.

[image]

```
function onInstall() {
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Import Question & Send Email')
    .addItem('Import Question', 'importQuestion')
    .addItem('Send Report by e-mail', 'sendReport')
    .addToUi();
}

function importQuestion() {
    var status = getQuestionAsCSV(metabaseQuestionNum, true);
    var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var metabaseQuestionNum = scriptProp.getProperty('QUESTION_ID');

    var log = {
      'user': Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      'function': 'importQuestion',
      'questionNumber': metabaseQuestionNum,
      'status': status
    };
    if (log.status === true) {
      console.log(log);
    } else {
      console.error(log);
    }
}

function getSheetNumbers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var questionNumbers = [];
  for (var i in sheets) {
    var sheetName = sheets[i].getName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf('(metabase/') > -1) {
      var questionMatch = sheetName.match('\(metabase\/[0-9]+\)');
      if (questionMatch !== null) {
        var questionNumber = questionMatch[0].match('[0-9]+')[0];
        if (!isNaN(questionNumber) && questionNumber !== '') {
          questionNumbers.push({
            'questionNumber': questionNumber,
            'sheetName': sheetName
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return questionNumbers;
}

function getToken(baseUrl, username, password) {
  var sessionUrl = baseUrl + "api/session";
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password
    })
  };
  var response;
  try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sessionUrl, options);
  } catch (e) {
    throw (e);
  }
  var token = JSON.parse(response).id;
  return token;
}

function getQuestionAndFillSheet(baseUrl, token, metabaseQuestionNum, sheetName) {
  var questionUrl = baseUrl + "api/card/" + metabaseQuestionNum + "/query/csv";

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Metabase-Session": token
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  var response;
  try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(questionUrl, options);
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      'success': false,
      'error': e
    };
  }
  var statusCode = response.getResponseCode();

  if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 202) {
    var values = Utilities.parseCsv(response.getContentText());
    try {
      fillSheet(values, sheetName);
      return {
        'success': true
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        'success': false,
        'error': e
      };
    }
  } else if (statusCode == 401) {
    var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var username = scriptProp.getProperty('USERNAME');
    var password = scriptProp.getProperty('PASSWORD');

    var token = getToken(baseUrl, username, password);
    scriptProp.setProperty('TOKEN', token);
    var e = "Error: Could not retrieve question. Metabase says: '" + response.getContentText() + "'. Please try again in a few minutes.";
    return {
      'success': false,
      'error': e
    };
  } else {
    var e = "Error: Could not retrieve question. Metabase says: '" + response.getContentText() + "'. Please try again later.";
    return {
      'success': false,
      'error': e
    };
  }
}

function fillSheet(values, sheetName) {
  var colLetters = ["N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BK", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BP", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BU", "BV", "BW", "BX", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CJ", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CP", "CQ", "CR", "CS", "CT", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF", "DG", "DH", "DI", "DJ", "DK", "DL", "DM", "DN", "DO", "DP", "DQ", "DR", "DS", "DT", "DU", "DV", "DW", "DX", "DY", "DZ", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "EE", "EF", "EG", "EH", "EI", "EJ", "EK", "EL", "EM", "EN", "EO", "EP", "EQ", "ER", "ES", "ET", "EU", "EV", "EW", "EX", "EY", "EZ", "FA", "FB", "FC", "FD", "FE", "FF", "FG", "FH", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FL", "FM", "FN", "FO", "FP", "FQ", "FR", "FS", "FT", "FU", "FV", "FW", "FX", "FY", "FZ", "GA", "GB", "GC", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GJ", "GK", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GO", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GV", "GW", "GX", "GY", "GZ", "HA", "HB", "HC", "HD", "HE", "HF", "HG", "HH", "HI", "HJ", "HK", "HL", "HM", "HN", "HO", "HP", "HQ", "HR", "HS", "HT", "HU", "HV", "HW", "HX", "HY", "HZ", "IA", "IB", "IC", "ID", "IE", "IF", "IG", "IH", "II", "IJ", "IK", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IP", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "IU", "IV", "IW", "IX", "IY", "IZ", "JA", "JB", "JC", "JD", "JE", "JF", "JG", "JH", "JI", "JJ", "JK", "JL", "JM", "JN", "JO", "JP", "JQ", "JR", "JS", "JT", "JU", "JV", "JW", "JX", "JY", "JZ"];

  var sheet;
  if (sheetName == false) {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  } else {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('AUTO-productivity');
  }

  var range = sheet.getRange(1,14,1000,4);
  range.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  var rows = values;
  var header = rows[0];
  var minCol = colLetters[0];
  var maxCol = colLetters[header.length - 1];
  var minRow = 1;
  var maxRow = rows.length;
  var range = sheet.getRange(minCol + minRow + ":" + maxCol + maxRow);
  range.setValues(rows);
}

function getQuestionAsCSV(metabaseQuestionNum, sheetName) {
  var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var baseUrl = scriptProp.getProperty('BASE_URL');
  var username = scriptProp.getProperty('USERNAME');
  var password = scriptProp.getProperty('PASSWORD');
  var token = scriptProp.getProperty('TOKEN');
  var metabaseQuestionNum = scriptProp.getProperty('QUESTION_ID');

  if (!token) {
    token = getToken(baseUrl, username, password);
    scriptProp.setProperty('TOKEN', token);
  }

  status = getQuestionAndFillSheet(baseUrl, token, metabaseQuestionNum, sheetName);
  return status;
}
```

Comment: are you running a live published version or a dev version?

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for answer me. I don't know how to identify this. But I think it's not as a dev version. How can I do this?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Can you help me to understand how to publish a live version or solve this? I will be really grateful for your help. :)

Comment: You are saying that you have to re-authorize every week without any change to the code, and with the same login ?

Comment: Yes, @WaximCorp. Exactly whats you mentioned. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Actually no, but something must change, maybe the file ? Please provide the details of your authorization (the step just after ```continue``` on your screenshot)

Comment: @WaximCorp I updated my question with the screenshoots, can you have a look? I'm really grateful for you help. I hope I will solve this 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add scopes in manifest file

In project file, open Setup, and check `display manifest file "appsscript.json"`, and then open it.

Add:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
  ]
```

Reference :

- [Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes?hl=fr#viewing_scopes)
- [List of scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=fr#restricted-scopes&zippy=%2Cgmail-api%2Cdrive-api)